# Flutter web audioplayers can not mute volume on iPhone browser

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Flutter web can not mute volume on iPhone browser, I using package audioplayers, for android browser it working except iPhone browser

I also try use any packages for audio player but got still the same.

and also happen with iOS 17 as well